# Regex help for addon domain

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, addon-domain

we recently moved to an addon domain. I'm having problems with the redirect. I need to redirect for the following situations:

1. mydomain.com/mysubfolder/ to mysubfolder.com
2. mydomain.com/mysubfolder/wp-login.php? to mysubfolder.com/wp-login.php?
3. mydomain.com/mysubfolder/page/ to mysubfolder.com/page/ [there are many pages]

This is my current regex:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php
RewriteRule ^/mysubfolder/(.*)$ http://www.mysubfolder.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It takes care of points 1 and 2. But I can't figure how to take care of point 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex redirects all pages except wp-login.php. It also does not account for the URL without the trailing slash. I added the ? to correct this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewritRule ^/mysubfolder/?(.*)$ http://www.mysubfolder.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```